# Python code to swap on raydium

Tags: solana-program

Does anyone have an example of python code to swap on raydium? Without having to search for the pool keys (and having to search the raydium API) this process takes a long time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap transaction with raydium](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9136/swap-transaction-with-raydium)