# Swap transaction with raydium

Tags: solana-program

Could anyone give an example of python code that swaps on raydium?

Without having to make requests to the API: https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json

Because the above request takes a long time to serialize the response

Answer (score 1):

user [kokiez](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/6926/kokiez) did have some python code published on github that did a raydium swap all in python but I haven't been able to find it since.

The way I had solved this is I wrote all the code in typescript and then used a websocket to send the parameters from python to the typescript functions.

This could be helpful to get started for the code to swap on raydium: https://github.com/precious-void/raydium-swap

And regarding the pool keys, I have found two ways to get it reliably:

1. FalconHit API ( costs 0.12 SOL per month): https://docs.valguibs.com/
2. Using typescript to get the pool keys almost instantly only requiring the input and output token addresses. I had used some inspiration from [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/faster-method-to-retrieve-pool-keys-raydium) post. Here is what the code somewhat looks like:

```
import { PublicKey, Commitment, Connection } from '@solana/web3.js'
import {
  LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4,
  Liquidity,
  LiquidityPoolKeysV4,
  MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3,
  Market,
  SPL_MINT_LAYOUT
} from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk'
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()

// const rpcCon = new Connection(process.env.WEB3_SOL_PROVIDER, { commitment: 'finalized' })

async function getPoolKeys(connection: Connection, base: PublicKey, quote: PublicKey, commitment: Commitment = 'finalized') {
    const rsp = await fetchMarketAccounts(connection, base, quote, commitment)
    const poolKeys = await formatAmmKeysById(rsp[0].id, connection)
    return poolKeys
}
  
async function formatAmmKeysById(id: string, connection: Connection): Promise<LiquidityPoolKeysV4> {
    const account = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(id))
    if (account === null) throw Error(' get id info error ')
    const info = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data)

    const marketId = info.marketId
    const marketAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(marketId)
    if (marketAccount === null) throw Error(' get market info error')
    const marketInfo = MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.decode(marketAccount.data)

    const lpMint = info.lpMint
    const lpMintAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(lpMint)
    if (lpMintAccount === null) throw Error(' get lp mint info error')
    const lpMintInfo = SPL_MINT_LAYOUT.decode(lpMintAccount.data)

    return {
        id: new PublicKey(id),
        baseMint: info.baseMint,
        quoteMint: info.quoteMint,
        lpMint: info.lpMint,
        baseDecimals: info.baseDecimal.toNumber(),
        quoteDecimals: info.quoteDecimal.toNumber(),
        lpDecimals: lpMintInfo.decimals,
        version: 4,
        programId: account.owner,
        authority: Liquidity.getAssociatedAuthority({ programId: account.owner }).publicKey,
        openOrders: info.openOrders,
        targetOrders: info.targetOrders,
        baseVault: info.baseVault,
        quoteVault: info.quoteVault,
        withdrawQueue: info.withdrawQueue,
        lpVault: info.lpVault,
        marketVersion: 3,
        marketProgramId: info.marketProgramId,
        marketId: info.marketId,
        marketAuthority: Market.getAssociatedAuthority({ programId: info.marketProgramId, marketId: info.marketId }).publicKey,
        marketBaseVault: marketInfo.baseVault,
        marketQuoteVault: marketInfo.quoteVault,
        marketBids: marketInfo.bids,
        marketAsks: marketInfo.asks,
        marketEventQueue: marketInfo.eventQueue,
        lookupTableAccount: PublicKey.default,
    }
    }

async function fetchMarketAccounts(connection: Connection, base: PublicKey, quote: PublicKey, commitment: Commitment = 'finalized') {
    const marketProgramId = new PublicKey('675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8')
    const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
        marketProgramId,
        {
        commitment,
        filters: [
            { dataSize: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.span },
            {
            memcmp: {
                offset: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.offsetOf("baseMint"),
                bytes: base.toBase58(),
            },
            },
            {
            memcmp: {
                offset: LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.offsetOf("quoteMint"),
                bytes: quote.toBase58(),
            },
            },
        ],
        }
    );

    return accounts.map(({ pubkey, account }) => ({
        id: pubkey.toString(),
        ...LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data),
      }));
    }

// getPoolKeys(rpcCon, new PublicKey('HZ4Qund5mESBvNngcGNGXrsjAUjvZGP8pNcVwANnQMRG'), new PublicKey('So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112'))

export default getPoolKeys
```

If you have any question, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: hey @sashavsthewrld, thanks for this. I used the code you sent and I could get the pool. II'm using this https://github.com/precious-void/raydium-swap as well. So instead of using the pool sending the `poolInfo` as `radyium-swap` does, I sent the `poolKey` got from your function `getPoolKeys` but then I received an error: `lookupTableAddress: [poolKeys.lookupTableAccount].filter((i) => i && !i.equals(PublicKey.default)),` any idea of what could be the issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I formatted the response to match with the `liquidity/mainnet.json` and using one token as example, I noticed the `lookupTableAccount` in your code is returning the default one, which is different than the one present in `liquidity/mainnet.json`

Comment: Hey @Lücks I'm really sorry for the very delayed response, I am currently working on the issue you mentioned and will get back to you as soon as I got a solution.